# What could be the cause of a pyinstaller made .exe restarting itself even after keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I have inadvertently created Frankenstein.

Everything runs fine in the interpreter, but after running `python pyinstaller.py --onefile myFile.py` to make an .exe, upon running it starts behaving oddly. It seems to call its `main()` function seemingly randomly -- even after a keyboard interrupt to break out, it resurrects itself.

The code looks like this:

```
def main():
    print 'DO NOT CLOSE!'
    count = 0
    lastTime =  ((time.localtime()[4])*60) + (time.localtime()[5])
    sShot = ImageGrab.grab()
    saveSnap(count, lastTime)
    currentScreen = grab()
    while True:
        if currentScreen == grab():
            pass
        else:

            count += 1
            saveSnap(count, lastTime)
            currentScreen = grab()
            lastTime = ((time.localtime()[4])*60) + (time.localtime()[5])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pretty simple stuff, and like I said, it works fine in the interpreter. All it does it search for changes on screen and then timeStamps a snapshot.

What would be causing to randomly fire `main()`? It sometimes does it even before keyboard interrupt.

Comment: how many times `'DO NOT CLOSE!'` is printed?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian It prints initial upon running, and then 3 or 4 seconds later it prints again. Then if I do a Keyboard interrupt, once again in about 3-4 seconds `main()` gets called and "do not close" gets printed.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the `ImageGrab` module uses the `multiprocessing` module to launch a subprocess that collects the image, and that subprocess causes problems with a single-file PyInstaller executable. The problem is that Windows doesn't have a spawn command, and it just reruns the executable. You have to [tweak some environment variables](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing) to avoid the random rerunning of your program.